# Crazy Blazin' DOM Injection

Tags: grid, fastest-code, javascript, css, browser

## Introduction

This problem is a challenge that has to do with DOM manipulation at scale and overcoming some issues that may be inherent in dealing with the DOM.

- This challenge is interesting because limitations push us to think through things differently and lean on the strengths of languages different than what we usually use.
- I created this challenge myself based on a real world problem I ran into myself (details can be provided if needed). If this challenge has any relation to a differently know problem, those similarities are coincidental.

This challenge will be scored based on fastest execution.

## Challenge

You must render one of the challenge levels in the Chrome web browser (84.0.4147.89 for standardization purposes) (submissions will need to be JavaScript functions for timing purposes):

- [easy](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/1000-cells.html)
- [medium](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/10000-cells.html)
- [hard](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/100000-cells.html)

Using JavaScript please complete the following:

1. Get each table displayed and add a class `table-n` to each table where `n` is a zero based index of order of the table on the screen. If a table is nested within a table the parent would be N and the child would be N+1 with the next table being N+2.
2. Get each row displayed in each table and add a class of `table-n-row-r` where `r` is a zero based index of rows in the table represented by `table-n`.
3. Get each cell displayed in each table and add a class of `table-n-row-r-cell-c` where `c` is a zero based index of cells in a row represented by `table-n-row-r`.

At the end of the challenge the web page should still be able to be interacted through in the browser, and a call to `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` should return one and only one cell from the DOM.

Any method available to you as valid as long as:

1. Access to one of the difficulty levels has been done through Chrome (84.0.4147.89)
2. The URL of the browser and the page displayed doesn't change
3. A call to `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` returns only one element

## Output Examples

For this example we're using the [easy](https://dodzidenudzakuma.com/1000-cells.html) level as input.

The abbreviated output in the DOM should be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Code Golf Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table-0">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-0-row-0">
                <th class="table-0-row-0-cell-0">1</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-0-row-1">
                <td class="table-0-row-1-cell-0">11</td>
                <td class="table-0-row-1-cell-1">12</td>
                ...
            </tr>
            ...
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

There are only `<td>` and `<th>` elements used as cell elements for the challenge.

As long as `document.getElementsByClassName('table-n-row-r-cell-c');` returns an element with this class, we're good to go.

## Qualifying Entries

All entries need to have an execution speed of under 40 seconds for at least one difficulty level to qualify.

Timing starts when your algorithm starts, but after the page has loaded completely as all elements must be available (the browser spinner has stopped spinning).

Calculate the runtime for your method by calling `performance.now()` before and and after your injection method, and subtracting the first from the second as in the example below.

```
let t0 = performance.now();
doSomething()   // <---- The function you're measuring time for 
let t1 = performance.now();
let totalTime = t1 - t0;
```

## Winner

The entry that handles the highest difficulty within 40 seconds wins. Ties are broken by execution time at that difficulty.

Comment: It was. Then it was asked to be posted in the sandbox for review, I deleted it and posted it in the sandbox for review. It was reviewed by @Bubbler and  FryAmTheEggman . Additions and edits were made according to their suggestions.

Is there any reason that it doesn't meet standards now?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman is there any reason that this doesn't meet standards after our review and discussion?

Comment: I totally forgot, welcome back to CG.SE!

Comment: Ignoring the specifics of this question, it is generally recommended that you keep a submission in the Sandbox for around 3 days, just to make sure that plenty of people have the chance to read over it. Furthermore, it doesn't hurt to advertise in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) asking for feedback on Sandboxed proposals. For next time, I would definitely recommend sticking by the general recommendations (i.e. 3 days, or a score of +3) for how long you should leave a proposal in the Sandbox

Comment: Well, you did not make each change that was suggested, but generally this is much better. I think there are some clarity issues, which might be a part of why you are receiving downvotes. Since I am not particularly familiar with this area I can't really suggest how to improve that.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I did add the changes. You it was recommended for clarity on the JS function, that was added. No bonuses or penalties for different difficulty levels (that was modified as asked). More accurate way to measure time, that was modified as well. The levels are still there, but there is no bonus, they are just used for tie breakers suggested by Bubbler.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you changed them to be a tiebreaker. That is not clear immediately from the way you wrote it, since you kept the wording about implementing any one of them. Unless I am misreading something, you also have a typo in the scoring where you say the higher difficulty is the primary condition but higher difficulty is also the tiebreak - presumable one of these should be lower?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I will fix that typo. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: And accounting for the specifics of this question, I'd suggest Sandboxing for much longer than the general guideline of 3 days. This is a fastest-code challenge, which tend to be harder to specify and balance than code golf; it has multiple difficulty levels; and, it deals with a specific language, which restricts who can give feedback on it.

Comment: As someone who didn't know what a DOM is, I accept that I'm not the audience for this challenge. But, I'd prefer to realize that immediately on starting to read it. (And while I didn't downvote for this, others might have.) Note that because tags are displayed at the bottom of a question (which I wish SE would change), it's not immediately clear from the intro section that this is a language-specific question for Javascript, dealing with browsers and CSS. So I'd suggest putting a sentence about that at the very start, noting there that this challenge is about fastest execution.

Comment: May I assume all tables contains exactly 10 rows, 1 thead, 1 tbody after thead, 1 row in thead, 9 rows in tbody, 10 cells in each row?

Answer (score 1):

## About 200 ms

```
function mark() {
  var t = 0, tp = '';
  var c = [], i = { r: 0, p: '', c: 0 };
  var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var length = elements.length, index, v;
  for (index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
    v = elements[index];
    switch (v.tagName) {
      case 'TH':
      case 'TD':
        v.className = i.p + i.c++;
        if (i.c == 10 && i.r == 10) {
          i = c.pop();
        }
        continue;
      case 'TR':
        v.className = i.p = i.t + i.r++;
        i.c = 0;
        i.p += '-col-';
        continue;
      case 'TABLE':
        v.className = tp = 'table-' + t++;
        tp += '-row-';
        c.push(i);
        i = { t: tp, r: 0, p: '', c: 0 };
    }
  }
}
```

If your code runs more than 2s, you must do something wrong. I believe.